# Air conditioner on rainy day

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I got a new LG 1.5 ton AC(Air conditioner) . It's summer time here and the temperature reaches approx 40 degree Celsius at peak time. And it's working quite satisfactorily. But in the last two weeks it rained twice lightly. After each rain the outside temperature dropped approx to 35 Celsius. Then I noticed that the AC is not cooling the room that fast compared to non rainy days. Is it expected and some physics behind it? Or fault with AC?

Note: When no rain, 24 degree is my comfort level. But after rain I have to keep it around 18 degree for the same effect. One thing I missed mentioning is this happens only at day time. At night time the ac cools pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the latent heat of vaporization is involved here.Freon, or coolant, is the chemical in the air conditioning system that cools the air by using the principle of cooling effect due to evaporation.As you know from elementary chemistry, the rate of evaporation depends on

1. Temperature(directly proportional)
2. Wind speed(directly proportional)
3. Humidity(inversely proportional)

The rate of evaporation is higher on dry,hot day thus cooling the system more effectively due to cooling effect of evaporation. Also humidity has massive effect on the *'feels- like temperature*'

But at night all these effects are less visible due to the drop in temperature

Comment: This answer is a little confusing, IMHO. The freon (or other coolant fluid) in an air conditioner is not exposed to the atmosphere, so why should the ambient humidity affect it?

Comment: An air conditioner collects hot air from a given space, processes it within itself with the help of a refrigerant and a bunch of coils and then releases cool air into the same space where the hot air had originally been collected. This is essentially how all  air conditioners work.

Comment: https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/air-conditioner-ac-work.html

Comment: Although there is a  dehumdifier, it isn't 100% effective especially in monsoon regions (Southeast Asia) and equatorial regions.